# How to verify .cloudfunctions.net domain in Google cloud functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

There are similar topics on SO which describes how to verify domain with path, for example `us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/googleDomainVerification/`. But how to verify domain without `googleDomainVerification` path?

Comment: Edit your question. What are you trying to accomplish? There are many methods to verify a domain (meaning that you own/control that domain) but most require that you control the DNS server. For Google services, Google offers an interface to create custom domains and certificates.

Comment: I'm following this https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/intelligent-gmail-processing?hl=en&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fcodelabs.developers.google.com%2F#3 tutorial It requires making APIs & Services > Domain verification.

Comment: Edit your question so that all details are in your question and do not require reading an external link.

Answer (score 0):

The domains of the cloud functions do not require verification (this is verified by google), since you are not activating any additional scope it is not necessary to start the verification process of the application.

If you are following the tutorial, this will work for your test Gmail account, without any additional process.

Unverified apps are limited to up to 100 users.